# Linear orderings in an undirected graph

Tags: graph-theory

[image]

A question I am solving requires "any linear ordering of variables in which each variable is assigned before all its children in the tree."

The two solutions of the given options are $C-A-B-D-E-F$ and $B-C-D-A-E-F$

Since this is an undirected graph, it is not clear to me what are children of a node. How did the solution writer determine that $C-A-B-D-E-F$ and $B-C-D-A-E-F$ satisfy the property that "each variable is assigned before all its children in the tree"?

Answer (score 0):

It seems unlikely that these are two solutions, because no matter how you choose to direct the edges, either B is a child of C, or C is a child of B. However, C is before B in your first ordering, and C is after B in the second one.